# Bash script in terminal on boot

Tags: boot, command-line, bash

Is there any way to run a `.sh` script in a terminal window on boot?

My computer boots slowly and I want to be able to press the button and leave to save a lot of time.

This script is a looping `server` and requires `command input` and `monitoring`. It must not run invisible or I will be unable to shut it down properly, which will result in damage to the files.

`Ubuntu 14.04LTS 32bit`

Comment: When do you want to run it? After login or even before? And which Ubuntu flavour (Desktop Environment) are you using or do you prefer a terminal solution to set the autostart up?

Comment: What is a 'terminal solution'? I added the rest of the questions to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can try openvt , though interactive script on boot will be tricky.

this answer might help. answer implements openvt
       [link](https://superuser.com/questions/584931/howto-start-an-interactive-script-at-ubuntu-startup)